# The functions addresses of runtime are different from ones come from the executable binary

Tags: android, c, clang

Under the aosp 6.0 source code, I want to build the fastboot with tracing calling status, so I added the following compile parameters "-g -finstrument-functions" to build the binary.

## First

I run the command "readelf -s xxxxxx(my target binary)", the function addresses are below:

```
124: 0000000000002390    69 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 usb_open
125: 00000000000021b0   306 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 usb_read
126: 0000000000002080   294 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 usb_write
127: 0000000000002340    71 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 usb_close
128: 00000000000022f0    68 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 usb_kick
129: 0000000000002670   151 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 usb_wait_for_disconnect
76: 0000000000001f60   286 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 main
```

## Second

I got the runtime function addresses via tracing functions like below:

```
void main_constructor( void )
{
    fp = fopen( "trace.txt", "w" );
    if (fp == NULL) exit(-1);
}

void main_deconstructor( void )
{
    fclose( fp );
}

void __cyg_profile_func_enter( void *this, void *callsite )
{
    fprintf(fp, "E%p\n", (int *)this);
}

void __cyg_profile_func_exit( void *this, void *callsite )
{
    fprintf(fp, "X%p\n", (int *)this);
}
```

However, the function addresses are like below:

```
E0x7fd2a83bbf60
E0x7fd2a83bc390
E0x7fd2a83bc3e0
```

Apparently, the functions address from running time are different from ones from the executable binary, the runningtime one is more 0X7fd2a83ba000 then the static one. After googling, it seems to be the dynamic library loading mode, but what I build is the executable binary. **I want to know how should I do to get the same functions addresses like ones from static binaries. Then I can use the addr2line to get the names of function to generate the calling status graph.**

(BTW, after my investigations, I found that the android 6.0 source code uses the clang to build the host X86/X86_64 programs, so I guess this problem is originated from some Clang's compiling parameters. Under the android 4.4, I can do this)

Thanks very much for any help!

Comment: You've made a lot of observations, but what's the question?

Comment: Are you trying to generate a stack trace?

Comment: My question is in bold mode,  I want to get same addresses via function profiling as ones from "readelf -s ..." way. Then I can get the right name of functions from running time. I hope everyone can get my question, thanks

Comment: yes, but the name can't be got via addr2line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your executable from AOSP is being compiled with the PIE (Position Independent Executable) flag. When the binary is mapped into memory, it won't be mapped at the exact same address every run. An offset (base) will be applied thus the difference in the pointer address. If you really want to disable PIE, add `LOCAL_NO_FPIE` to the fastboot makefile (system/core/fastboot/Android.mk). You will need to add it after `include $(CLEAR_VARS)`.

To verify it isnt compiled as a PIE, invoke `hardening-check <executable-file>`.